# diagnosing bias, variance from learning curve

Tags: machine-learning, classification, variance, bias

I was doing machine learning course at coursera and there was a lecture about diagnosing high bias, or high variance from learning curves. If anyone interested here is the lecture - https://class.coursera.org/ml-003/lecture/64. I just can't find it enywhere else, I mean in some serious literature. So my question is, if this is really good, or commonly used approach to diagnose bias - variance in **classification** task? Or are there any commonly used, probably preferable way how to determine bias, variance error part in **classification** task?

Any comment, point to useful resource would be very appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do a bias-variance analysis on a machine learning modelling process](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/268983/how-to-do-a-bias-variance-analysis-on-a-machine-learning-modelling-process)